Getting rid of sticky bar in puppeteer screenshot
So I am working on a project that requires me to take a screenshot of a Pinterest board, I kind of fixed my previous issues like lazy loading and the infinite scroll. I limited how many scrolls the program does to avoid it going on forever. But now my problem is that the navbar is showing up in the middle of the screenshot, and not matter what I use, it still shows up in the program. I've tried deleting the property through xpath, not sure if I did it correctly.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  // Navigate to the Pinterest board (or your target page)
  await page.goto('https://www.pinterest.com/NoMyCheesy/f-l-o-w-e-r-s/');
  
  // Wait for the sticky bar element using XPath
  const xpath = 'html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div';
  
  // Wait for the element using XPath, page.$x returns an array of elements
  const elements = await page.waitForSelector(xpath);

  // Check if any elements were found
  if (elements.length > 0) {
      const element = elements[0]; // Get the first matched element
      await element.evaluate(el => el.remove()); // Remove it from the DOM
  } else {
      console.log("Element not found");
  }
    // Zoom out (e.g., 50% zoom)
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.body.style.zoom = '0.5'; // Zoom out to 50%
    });

    // Scroll to load more pins
    await autoScroll(page, 15);  // Limit to 15 scrolls

    // Wait for images and network to stabilize
    await page.waitForFunction(() => {
        return document.readyState === 'complete' && window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource').every(e => e.initiatorType !== 'img' || e.responseEnd < performance.now() - 2000);
    }, { timeout: 20000 });

    // Take a full-page screenshot
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'yoursite.png',
        fullPage: true
    });

    await browser.close();
    console.log('Screenshot saved as yoursite.png');
})();

// Function to scroll down the page
async function autoScroll(page, maxScrolls) {
    await page.evaluate(async (maxScrolls) => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            let totalHeight = 0;
            let distance = 100;
            let scrolls = 0;  // Scrolls counter
            let timer = setInterval(() => {
                let scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;
                scrolls++;  // Increment counter

                // Stop scrolling if reached the end or the max number of scrolls
                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight - window.innerHeight || scrolls >= maxScrolls) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 3500);  // Scroll every 3.5 seconds
        });
    }, maxScrolls);  // Pass maxScrolls to the function
}


html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div is a very brittle selector that could fail easily, either matching nothing or the wrong thing. Prefer a class, attribute or id.

I modified your code and it worked:
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });

// Navigate to the Pinterest board (or your target page)
await page.goto('https://www.pinterest.com/NoMyCheesy/f-l-o-w-e-r-s/');

// Wait for the sticky bar element using XPath
const headerSelector = '[data-test-id="unauth-header"]'; //unauth
// const headerSelector = '#HeaderContent'; //auth

// Wait for the header element to appear
await page.waitForSelector(headerSelector);

await page.evaluate((headerSelector) => {
    const header = document.querySelector(headerSelector);
    header.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the element
}, headerSelector); // Hide the element

Changes:

Updated setViewport to the page.
Changed the header waiting selector from xPath to appropriate selector, choose between auth or unauth depends on your case (Your original xPath is not working on my end).
Hide the header instead of removing it from the DOM. You can set the opacity to 0 instead if you want, but both will work as is.

